# Using user defined variables in VBA with solver

Tags: vba, excel

The following code was generated from a solver macro and then modified a bit:

```
SolverOk SetCell:=flowmax, _
MaxMinVal:=1, _
ValueOf:=0, _
ByChange:= eastflow,westflow, _
Engine:=1, _
EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"

SolverAdd CellRef:=error, Relation:=2, FormulaText:="0"
SolverAdd CellRef:=eastflow, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:=westflow, Relation:=3, FormulaText:="1"
SolverAdd CellRef:=westincon, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=concontrol
SolverAdd CellRef:=westinfluo, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=fluocontrol
SolverAdd CellRef:=westincod, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=codcontrol
SolverAdd CellRef:=westinamm, Relation:=1, FormulaText:=ammcontrol
SolverSolve
```

The problem that I have is at the line of "ByChange".  It is not possible for me to reference cells, especially the "ByChange" cells.  The client must not see these values continually change as the solver runs, hence the variable usage.  But my syntax is wrong.

The main question is thus:  How do I use user defined variables in the ByChange parameter of solver.

Answer (score 0):

Can this dumb code help?

```
Application.ScreenUpdating=False
'your solver
Application.ScreenUpdating=true
```

Comment: Yes this would definitely help.  For future reference, do you know of a way to use the solver only in "code"?(not referencing a single cell)